# Exporting a table with some rows, importing the same table with more rows in R

Tags: r, import, export

I'm trying importing a dataframe with 1,622,401 rows since R to a .csv or .txt like this:

```
   write.table(x = TablaByV1Todo, file = "C:/Users/C15109/Desktop/Pruebas TRANSFINT/Primeras 7 bases/TablaByV1Todo.txt", quote = FALSE,sep = ";", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

When I import that table that I created and save in .txt format in R, in the environment shows me that this table has more rows 1,622,622. Something interesting is that the last row is the same row in both tables with different rows.

I don't know how can I save the table with exact rows in a .txt file.

I import with this code:

```
 TablaByV1Todo <- read.csv("C:/Users/C15109/Desktop/Pruebas TRANSFINT/Primeras 7 bases/Base1/TablaByV1Todo.txt", sep=";")
```

Comment: What is the code for your import command?  As in:  can you add the `read.table()` or (whatever you used) to your question above?

Comment: Thank you,@DanY.  Base1yValTodas <- read.csv("C:/Users/C15109/Desktop/Pruebas TRANSFINT/Primeras 7 bases/Base1/TablaByV1Todo.txt", sep=";")

Comment: You are writing a file "TablaByV1Semi.txt" to disk and then reading in "TablaByV1Todo.txt" (a different file)!

Comment: Ah no no, when I imported  the file, I changed the name for notice that the table I have in the  environment looks the same that the table I imported.

Comment: Your code literally does this:  `write.table(data, file="file1")`. And then:  `read.table("file2")`.  File1 and File2 are different files!  Fix this and then let me know if the problem is still occurring.

Comment: write.table(x = TablaByV1Todo, file = "C:/Users/C15109/Desktop/Pruebas TRANSFINT/Primeras 7 bases/TablaByV1Todo.txt", quote = FALSE,sep = ";",
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE) and then I import the same file like this: TablaByV1Todo <- read.csv("C:/Users/C15109/Desktop/Pruebas TRANSFINT/Primeras 7 bases/Base1/TablaByV1Todo.txt", sep=";") and the rows are different

Comment: OK - it sounds like we're getting past the naming thing (I do still hope Semi.txt isn't the problem)!  Try this:  have one version of the data (let's call it `data1`) in R.  Write that data to disk and then import it back into R with `read.table()` or whatever but call it `data2`.  So now you have (what should be) two identical copies of the data.frame in your global environment.  Now merge `data1` and `data2` with the merge argument `keep=all` and manually inspect the rows that don't merge.

Comment: I already did what you advised me to do. data1 in the environment had 1,622,401 and data2 had 1,622,652 rows. I did the merge function like this: union <- merge (data1, data2, keep = all). In the  environment, union had 1,623,936 rows. I don't understand why it has more rows than the two tables before.

Comment: I'm thinking that there is some character value that is getting treated like a new line.  You might be able to discover what that is by looking at the "extra" lines in data1.  Other than that, I don't know - sorry!